# Pancakeswap liqidty not working with forked token

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, binance-smart-chain, bep20, binance-chain

I have forked sprout token and I have changed basic things but I'm not sure that liquidity to pool is working or not please suggest me how I can sure that liquidity is working or also if is there any way to sending instead to pancakeswap liquidity pool to another wallet?

```
interface IUniswapV2Pair {
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    function name() external pure returns (string memory);
    function symbol() external pure returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external pure returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);
    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function DOMAIN_SEPARATOR() external view returns (bytes32);
    function PERMIT_TYPEHASH() external pure returns (bytes32);
    function nonces(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external;
    event Mint(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1);
    event Burn(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, address indexed to);
    event Swap(
        address indexed sender,
        uint amount0In,
        uint amount1In,
        uint amount0Out,
        uint amount1Out,
        address indexed to
    );
    event Sync(uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1);
    function MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY() external pure returns (uint);
    function factory() external view returns (address);
    function token0() external view returns (address);
    function token1() external view returns (address);
    function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast);
    function price0CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
    function price1CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
    function kLast() external view returns (uint);
    function mint(address to) external returns (uint liquidity);
    function burn(address to) external returns (uint amount0, uint amount1);
    function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external;
    function skim(address to) external;
    function sync() external;
    function initialize(address, address) external;
}

interface IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);
    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity);
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
    function removeLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function removeLiquidityWithPermit(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermit(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactTokens(
        uint amountOut,
        uint amountInMax,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactETH(uint amountOut, uint amountInMax, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) external pure returns (uint amountB);
    function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountOut);
    function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountIn);
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router02 is IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountETH);
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountETH);

    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
    function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable;
    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
}

contract CoinToken is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;

    mapping (address => uint256) private _rOwned;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _tOwned;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;
    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;
    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcluded;
    address[] private _excluded;
    address public _devWalletAddress;     // TODO - team wallet here
    uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
    uint256 private _tTotal;
    uint256 private _rTotal;
    uint256 private _tFeeTotal;
    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;
    uint256 private _decimals;
    uint256 public _taxFee;
    uint256 private _previousTaxFee;
    uint256 public _devFee;
    uint256 private _previousDevFee;
    uint256 public _liquidityFee;
    uint256 private _previousLiquidityFee;
    IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapV2Router;
    address public uniswapV2Pair;
    bool inSwapAndLiquify;
    bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = true;
    uint256 public _maxTxAmount;
    uint256 public numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
    event MinTokensBeforeSwapUpdated(uint256 minTokensBeforeSwap);
    event SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
    event SwapAndLiquify(
        uint256 tokensSwapped,
        uint256 ethReceived,
        uint256 tokensIntoLiqudity
    );
    
    modifier lockTheSwap {
        inSwapAndLiquify = true;
        _;
        inSwapAndLiquify = false;
    }
    
    constructor (string memory _NAME, string memory _SYMBOL, uint256 _DECIMALS, uint256 _supply, uint256 _txFee,uint256 _lpFee,uint256 _DexFee,address routerAddress,address feeaddress,address tokenOwner,address service) public payable {
        _name = _NAME;
        _symbol = _SYMBOL;
        _decimals = _DECIMALS;
        _tTotal = _supply * 10 ** _decimals;
        _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
        _taxFee = _txFee;
        _liquidityFee = _lpFee;
        _previousTaxFee = _txFee;
        
        _devFee = _DexFee;
        _previousDevFee = _devFee;
        _previousLiquidityFee = _lpFee;
        _maxTxAmount = (_tTotal * 5 / 1000) * 10 ** _decimals;
        numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity = (_tTotal * 5 / 10000) * 10 ** _decimals;
        _devWalletAddress = feeaddress;
        
        _rOwned[tokenOwner] = _rTotal;
        
        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress);
         // Create a uniswap pair for this new token
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());

        // set the rest of the contract variables
        uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
        
        //exclude owner and this contract from fee
        _isExcludedFromFee[tokenOwner] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
    
        _owner = tokenOwner;
        payable(service).transfer(msg.value);
        emit Transfer(address(0), tokenOwner, _tTotal);
        
        
    }

    function name() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _tTotal;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        if (_isExcluded[account]) return _tOwned[account];
        return tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"));
        return true;
    }

    function isExcludedFromReward(address account) public view returns (bool) {
        return _isExcluded[account];
    }

    function totalFees() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tFeeTotal;
    }

    function deliver(uint256 tAmount) public {
        address sender = _msgSender();
        require(!_isExcluded[sender], "Excluded addresses cannot call this function");
        (uint256 rAmount,,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rAmount);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tAmount);
    }

    function reflectionFromToken(uint256 tAmount, bool deductTransferFee) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(tAmount <= _tTotal, "Amount must be less than supply");
        if (!deductTransferFee) {
            (uint256 rAmount,,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rAmount;
        } else {
            (,uint256 rTransferAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rTransferAmount;
        }
    }

    function tokenFromReflection(uint256 rAmount) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(rAmount <= _rTotal, "Amount must be less than total reflections");
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        return rAmount.div(currentRate);
    }

    function excludeFromReward(address account) public onlyOwner() {
        require(!_isExcluded[account], "Account is already excluded");
        if(_rOwned[account] > 0) {
            _tOwned[account] = tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
        }
        _isExcluded[account] = true;
        _excluded.push(account);
    }

    function includeInReward(address account) external onlyOwner() {
        require(_isExcluded[account], "Account is already included");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_excluded[i] == account) {
                _excluded[i] = _excluded[_excluded.length - 1];
                _tOwned[account] = 0;
                _isExcluded[account] = false;
                _excluded.pop();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
        function _transferBothExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 tDev) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);        
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _takeDev(tDev);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }
    
    function excludeFromFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = true;
    }
    
    function includeInFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = false;
    }
    
    function setTaxFeePercent(uint256 taxFee) external onlyOwner() {
        _taxFee = taxFee;
    }

    function setDevFeePercent(uint256 devFee) external onlyOwner() {
        _devFee = devFee;
    }
    
    function setLiquidityFeePercent(uint256 liquidityFee) external onlyOwner() {
        _liquidityFee = liquidityFee;
    }
   
    function setMaxTxPercent(uint256 maxTxPercent) public onlyOwner {
        _maxTxAmount = maxTxPercent  * 10 ** _decimals;
    }
    
    function setDevWalletAddress(address _addr) public onlyOwner {
        _devWalletAddress = _addr;
    }
    

    function setSwapAndLiquifyEnabled(bool _enabled) public onlyOwner {
        swapAndLiquifyEnabled = _enabled;
        emit SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(_enabled);
    }
    
     //to recieve ETH from uniswapV2Router when swaping
    receive() external payable {}

    function _reflectFee(uint256 rFee, uint256 tFee) private {
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rFee);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tFee);
    }

    function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 tDev) = _getTValues(tAmount);
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tDev, _getRate());
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tDev);
    }

    function _getTValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 tFee = calculateTaxFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tLiquidity = calculateLiquidityFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tDev = calculateDevFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tLiquidity).sub(tDev);
        return (tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tDev);
    }

    function _getRValues(uint256 tAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 tDev, uint256 currentRate) private pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rFee = tFee.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rDev = tDev.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rTransferAmount = rAmount.sub(rFee).sub(rLiquidity).sub(rDev);
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee);
    }

    function _getRate() private view returns(uint256) {
        (uint256 rSupply, uint256 tSupply) = _getCurrentSupply();
        return rSupply.div(tSupply);
    }

    function _getCurrentSupply() private view returns(uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rSupply = _rTotal;
        uint256 tSupply = _tTotal;      
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_rOwned[_excluded[i]] > rSupply || _tOwned[_excluded[i]] > tSupply) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
            rSupply = rSupply.sub(_rOwned[_excluded[i]]);
            tSupply = tSupply.sub(_tOwned[_excluded[i]]);
        }
        if (rSupply < _rTotal.div(_tTotal)) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
        return (rSupply, tSupply);
    }
    
    function _takeLiquidity(uint256 tLiquidity) private {
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        _rOwned[address(this)] = _rOwned[address(this)].add(rLiquidity);
        if(_isExcluded[address(this)])
            _tOwned[address(this)] = _tOwned[address(this)].add(tLiquidity);
    }
    
    function _takeDev(uint256 tDev) private {
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        uint256 rDev = tDev.mul(currentRate);
        _rOwned[_devWalletAddress] = _rOwned[_devWalletAddress].add(rDev);
        if(_isExcluded[_devWalletAddress])
            _tOwned[_devWalletAddress] = _tOwned[_devWalletAddress].add(tDev);
    }
    
    function calculateTaxFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount.mul(_taxFee).div(
            10**2
        );
    }

    function calculateDevFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount.mul(_devFee).div(
            10**2
        );
    }

    function calculateLiquidityFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount.mul(_liquidityFee).div(
            10**2
        );
    }
    
    function removeAllFee() private { 
        _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
        _previousDevFee = _devFee;
        _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
        
        _taxFee = 0;
        _devFee = 0;
        _liquidityFee = 0;
    }
    
    function restoreAllFee() private {
        _taxFee = _previousTaxFee;
        _devFee = _previousDevFee;
        _liquidityFee = _previousLiquidityFee;
    }
    
    function isExcludedFromFee(address account) public view returns(bool) {
        return _isExcludedFromFee[account];
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) private {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        if(from != owner() && to != owner())
            require(amount <= _maxTxAmount, "Transfer amount exceeds the maxTxAmount.");

        uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        
        if(contractTokenBalance >= _maxTxAmount)
        {
            contractTokenBalance = _maxTxAmount;
        }
        
        bool overMinTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance >= numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
        if (
            overMinTokenBalance &&
            !inSwapAndLiquify &&
            from != uniswapV2Pair &&
            swapAndLiquifyEnabled
        ) {
            contractTokenBalance = numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
            swapAndLiquify(contractTokenBalance);
        }
        
        bool takeFee = true;
        if(_isExcludedFromFee[from] || _isExcludedFromFee[to]){
            takeFee = false;
        }
        
        _tokenTransfer(from,to,amount,takeFee);
    }

    function swapAndLiquify(uint256 contractTokenBalance) private lockTheSwap {
        uint256 half = contractTokenBalance.div(2);
        uint256 otherHalf = contractTokenBalance.sub(half);
        uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;
        swapTokensForEth(half); 
        uint256 newBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);
        addLiquidity(otherHalf, newBalance);
        emit SwapAndLiquify(half, newBalance, otherHalf);
    }

    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0, // accept any amount of ETH
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 ethAmount) private {
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
            address(this),
            tokenAmount,
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            owner(),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    function _tokenTransfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount,bool takeFee) private {
        if(!takeFee)
            removeAllFee();
        
        if (_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferFromExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferToExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferBothExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else {
            _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
        }
        
        if(!takeFee)
            restoreAllFee();
    }

    function _transferStandard(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 tDev) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _takeDev(tDev);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _transferToExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 tDev) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);           
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _takeDev(tDev);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _transferFromExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 tDev) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);   
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _takeDev(tDev);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }
    
    function setRouterAddress(address newRouter) external onlyOwner {
        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(newRouter);
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());
        uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
    }

    function setNumTokensSellToAddToLiquidity(uint256 amountToUpdate) external onlyOwner {
        numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity = amountToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The token balance of your contract, and other validations, is what dictates if swapAndLiquify should be run.

```
bool overMinTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance >= numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
if (
    overMinTokenBalance &&
    !inSwapAndLiquify &&
    from != uniswapV2Pair &&
    swapAndLiquifyEnabled
) {
    contractTokenBalance = numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
    swapAndLiquify(contractTokenBalance);
}
```

If token balance is greater than `numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity`, and swap and liquify is enabled, and not in swap and liquify process, and it is not a transfer from pair, then execute swapAndLiquify.

The only way to test this is by deploying to testnet, set a very low value for `numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity` and start doing transactions (buy,sell,transfer). First thing u will notice is that the token contract will start to hold tokens, and suddenly after reaching `numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity` you will see a big log of transfer in the transactions (swaps,liquify,token transfer, etc). This process is normally triggered by a sell or transfer. Buys will not trigger it because buy transactions comes from the pair address.

About sending to other wallets instead of PCS LP, yes, it is possible, you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

We can't do this on the testnet. I really don't know why. When overMin Token Balance returns true, trades on pancakeswap cannot be made and add LP does not work.